# A sum involving binomial coefficients, powers and alternating signs

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients, factorial

How to prove that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n \choose k} k^n = n!
$$
using mathematical induction? Please, do not use definition of Stirling number etc. algebra tricks.

Comment: Have you any thoughts on this yourself? Playing around with sums like this is usually the best first step.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515281/deduce-formula-for-sum-j-0m-m-choose-j-1j-jm1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369041/proving-a-closed-form-of-sum-j-0m-binommj-1m-jjk-for-0-leq-k-l, ...

Answer (score 6):

*Suggested intro*: maybe these solutions don't meet the OP's specific requirements, but I think that they're worth making available anyway.

---

$\color{red}{n!}$ is the number of bijective functions from $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $A$.

Let we say that a function $f:A\to A$ has *type $k$* if $|f(A)|=k$. The number of functions with type $\leq n$ is simply given by $n^n$, i.e. the number of all possible functions from $A$ to $A$. The number of functions with type $\leq(n-1)$ is given by $\binom{n}{n-1}$ (the number of ways for choosing $(n-1)$ elements in $A$) times $(n-1)^n$ (the number of functions from $A$ to a set with $(n-1)$ elements).
By the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of functions with type $n$ (i.e. the number of bijective functions) is given by:

$$ n^n-\binom{n}{n-1}(n-1)^n+\binom{n}{n-1}(n-2)^n-\ldots = \color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^n}. $$

---

Alternative proof. Let $\delta$ be the operator that maps a polynomial $p(x)$ into $p(x+1)-p(x)$.
The following properties are trivial to prove:

1. If $\partial p$ (the degree of $p$) is $\geq 1$, the degree of $\delta p$ is $\partial p-1$;
2. If the leading term of $p(x)$ is $a x^n$, the leading term of $\delta p(x)$ is $an x^{n-1}$, i.e. $\delta$ acts on the leading term like the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$.

Since our sum is just $\delta^n p(0)$ with $p(x)=x^n$, by (2.) it follows that our sum equals $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 1 = n!$.

Comment: the OP did ask for a solution by induction without tricks :)

Comment: @gt6989b: What is the point of doing math avoiding tricks? Tricks are the heart of problem solving.

Comment: i have a feeling in OP's case it is to learn proofs by mathematical induction

Comment: i wouldn't downvote actually

Comment: Please don’t delete it; both solutions are worth having around, and (as usual) I’m partial to the first one. What you might do is preface it with a statement to the effect that you realize that these solutions don’t meet the OP’s specific requirements, but you think that they’re worth making available anyway; I’ve done that on occasion.

Comment: I like the second proof. It's a bit like what happens with the [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform), and the form of the sum suggests making use of it, however it does not work because $k^n$ depends on $n$.

Comment: +1. Nice answer. I'm expecting sometimes in the future a question with the condition "don't write".

Comment: hmm... nice solution with combinatorical proof. But i don't understand why using  inclusion-exclusion principle we have this sum....

Comment: @M.Red: number of functions with type $n$ is given by the number of functions with type $\leq n$ minus the number of functions with type $(n-1)$. The number of functions with type $(n-1)$ is given by the number of functions with type $\leq(n-1)$ minus the number of functions with type $(n-2)$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually carrying out a proof by induction seems to be quite difficult. I found it easiest to prove the following stronger result (by induction on $n$):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^m=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }0\le m<n\\
n!,&\text{ if }m=n\;.
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Assume that $(1)$ holds for a specific $n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
(n+1)!&=(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}(n+1-k)\binom{n+1}kk^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}(n+1)\binom{n+1}kk^n-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n+1}kk^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^{n+1}\\
&\qquad-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+1-k}(n+1)\binom{n+1}kk^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^{n+1}-(n+1)^{n+1}\\
&\qquad-(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^{n+1}-(n+1)^{n+1}\\
&\qquad+(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left(\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)k^n\;.
\end{align*}$$

We’d like to show that

$$(n+1)!=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^{n+1}\;,$$

so we’d like to show that

$$(n+1)^{n+1}-(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n+1}kk^n=0$$

or, equivalently, that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^n=(n+1)^n-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n+1}kk^n=0\;.$$

And in fact

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\left(\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)k^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n}kk^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n}{k-1}k^n\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^n+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k(k+1)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k\big((k+1)^n-k^n\big)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}mk^m\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}m\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^m\\
&=0\;,
\end{align*}$$

since by the induction hypothesis

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^m=0$$

for $0\le m<n$. This shows that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^{n+1}=(n+1)!\;,$$

and it only remains to show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^m=0\tag{2}$$

when $0\le m\le n$.

Now

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}kk^m&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\left(\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)k^m\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n}kk^m+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n}{k-1}k^m\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^m+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k(k+1)^m\;.
\end{align*}$$

If $m=n$, this is

$$\begin{align*}
-n!+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k(k+1)^n&=-n!+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k\sum_{\ell=0}^n\binom{n}\ell k^\ell\\
&=-n!+\sum_{\ell=0}^n\binom{n}\ell\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^\ell\\
&=-n!+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^n+\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}\ell\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^\ell\\
&=-n!+n!+\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}\ell\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^\ell\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}\ell\cdot0\\
&=0\;.
\end{align*}$$

And if $0\le m<n$, it’s simply

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k(k+1)^m&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k\sum_{\ell=0}^m\binom{m}\ell k^m\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^m\binom{m}\ell\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}kk^m\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^m\binom{m}\ell\cdot0\\
&=0.
\end{align*}$$

This establishes $(2)$ and concludes the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

**Base Case**  $n=1$, check whether the equality holds (you should have just 2 terms in the sum)

**Inductive Step**

Assume this holds for $n = 1, 2, \ldots, N$ and show this for $n = N+1$.
You will have to simplify the terms of the summation to express 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N+1} (-1)^{N+1-k}{N+1 \choose k} k^{N+1}
$$
in terms of
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N} (-1)^{N-k}{N \choose k} k^{N}
$$