# Summing even and odd terms of binomial coefficients, with increasing powers of 2 and alternating signs

Tags: binomial-coefficients

For a complex number $z$, let $(1+z)^{15}=a_{0}+a_{1} z+\cdots+a_{15} z^{15}$. The value of
$$
\left(a_{0}-4 a_{2}+16 a_{4}+\cdots-2^{14} a_{14}\right)^{2}+\left(2 a_{1}-8 a_{3}+32 a_{5} \cdots-2^{15} a_{15}\right)^{2}
$$

While I was entirely stumped by this question, I found some similar questions on here, specifically [A sum involving binomial coefficients, powers and alternating signs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942401/a-sum-involving-binomial-coefficients-powers-and-alternating-signs). This did not equip me to be able to solve the above question, though, since this problem drops odd terms and even terms, alternates signs, AND has a factor of increasing powers of $2$, not to mention squares the result and then sums them.

I don't see how the sum can even be expressed as a binomial to somehow use calculus, nor do I see any algebraic manipulations; I've only managed to embarrassingly restate the problem statement as

$$ \left(\sum_{k=0}^{7} 2^{2 k}({ }^{15} C_{2 k})(-1)^k\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{7} 2^{2 k+1}\left({ }^{15} C_{2 k+1}\right)(-1)^k\right)^{2} $$

Comment: Substitute $z=2i$ into $(1+z)^{15}$, the first $(\ldots)^2$ is the real part squared, the second $(\ldots)^2$ is the imaginary part squared.

Comment: To think that mentioning z was a complex number was actually hinting towards something. I would not have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, you now know how to do this next time. The hint here is $z^2 = -4$.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation. We consider the polynomial
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(z)}&\color{blue}{=\left(\sum_{k=0}^7\binom{15}{2k}(-1)^k(2z)^{2k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=0}^7\binom{15}{2k+1}(-1)^k(2z)^{2k+1}\right)^2}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
and with respect to OPs expression we need to calculate $F(1)$.

> We obtain from (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{F(z)}&=\left(\sum_{{k=0}\atop{k\mathrm{\ even}}}^{15}\binom{15}{k}i^k(2z)^{k}\right)^2
> +\left(\frac{1}{i}\sum_{{k=0}\atop{k\mathrm{\ odd}}}^{15}\binom{15}{k}i^k(2z)^{k}\right)^2\\
> &=\left(\frac{(1+2iz)^{15}+(1-2iz)^{15}}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{i}\,\frac{(1+2iz)^{15}-(1-2iz)^{15}}{2}\right)^2\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\left((1+2iz)^{15}+(1-2iz)^{15}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}\left((1+2iz)^{15}-(1-2iz)^{15}\right)^2\\
> &=\left(1+2iz\right)^{15}\left(1-2iz\right)^{15}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(1+4z^2\right)^{15}}\\\\
> \color{blue}{F(1)}&=\color{blue}{5^{15}}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with another given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$F= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{7} 2^{2 k}({ }^{15} C_{2 k})(-1)^k\right)^{2}+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{7} 2^{2 k+1}\left({ }^{15} C_{2 k+1}\right)(-1)^k\right)^{2} $$
From binomial expansion we have

$S_1=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {2n+1 \choose 2k} x^{2k}=\frac{1}{2}[(1+ix)^{2n+1}+(1-ix)^{2n+1}]-(1+x^2)^{n+1/2} \cos (2n+1)t$,

$t=\tan^{-1}x.$

$S_2=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {2n+1 \choose 2k+1} x^{2k+1}=\frac{-i}{2}[(1+ix)^{2n+1}-(1-ix)^{2n+1}]=(1+x^2)^{n+1/2} \sin (2n+1)t.$

$F=S_1^2+S_2^2=(1+x^2)^{2n+1},\text{where} x=2, n=7$

So we get $F=5^{15}.$